# Jib plugin not able to recognize auth credentials

Tags: jib

I am trying to build and push my application docker image from my local machine to my docker hub registry with below configuration. But I am getting error stating "Task 'jibPush' not found in root project"

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.4.0'
}

group = 'com.learntech'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

jib {
    from {
        image = 'openjdk:17-slim'
    }
    container {
        jvmFlags = ['-Dmy.property=example.value', '-Xms512m', '-Xdebug']
        mainClass = 'mypackage.K8sLearningApplication'
        ports = ['8080']
        //labels = [key1:'value1', key2:'value2']
        //format = 'OCI'
    }
    to {
        image = 'k8-learning:latest'
        auth {
            username = 'userName'
            password = 'password'
        }
    }

}
```

Build command

```
./gradlew jibPush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `./gradlew jib`. The available tasks are `jib`, `jibDockerBuild`, and `jibBuildTar`.